# TFSBuild.proj import update - advice needed

Tags: tfsbuild, msbuildextensionpack

Have made some progress with our new Win 7 VS2008 Team System build server, by installing Sql Server 2008 express instead of SSE 2005. The next hurdle is that we are using VS2008 and our team project file imports the MSBuild extension pack for Sql Server 2005, which it seems will not work with Win 7 and Sql Server 2008. So instead we have installed the MSBuild extension pack dated October 2012, to the default path. Our build now fails at the off because the import cannot find "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks".

And I can't find it either!

Is this a version mismatch (in which case how to we get out of this hole) or am I being silly? The only files I can find are $(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Tfs2010.dll, which doesn't look right to me. The installed MSBuild Extension Pack help file doesn't cover this sort of thing, as far as I can tell, so I am at a loss.

TIA

Comment: I think I can see the problem - this is a Win-764bit server, so all 32bit stuff is installed in the "Program Files x86" folder, whereas the $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) path goes through the 64bit Program Files folder. So how can I best redirect things to the correct (Wow64) path?

Comment: Have you tried using $(MSBuildExtensionPath32)?

Comment: No - I wasn't aware of that option. It may solve the problem - I'll give it a go.

Comment: It worked! On to the next problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `$(MSBuildExtensionPath)` with `$(MSBuildExtensionPath32)` to make sure the Program Files (x86) directory can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making your build server match your dev environment as close as possible.  If your developers work on a 32-bit machine, with SQL 2005 installed, then I would try and have the build servers match.  Any software that needs to be installed on a developers machine (e.g. MSBuild extensions) should also be installed on the build server.

Comment: Good thought - but the old machine has an OEM XP licence and we can't transfer that to the new machine and can't get a new XP licence anymore (thanks Microsoft!). So we are being forced to use Windows 7 and hence Sql Server 2008 and that has set off a whole chain of dependency issues.